# Estimated time remaining, what am I missing?

Tags: c#

I think my logic is flawed....

in a loop I have:

```
int seconds = (int) (elapsed.TotalSeconds / ItemPos) * (Count - ItemPos);
```

this loop updates approximately once per second....

the problem I have is that seconds always ends up with a zero (0) value.

this is because the `ItemPos` value is always higher after first loop than `elapsed.TotalSeconds`.

So for example:

if 3 seconds pass

```
ItemCount = 20 , so 3/20 = 0.15 - rounds to zero.... 0 * anything = 0......
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first division is rounding to 0. Cast the operands to (float) first.

Comment: @EricLaw: TimeSpan.TotalSeconds is a `double`

Comment: @EricLaw - very nice... I'll add the solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer division always returns an int, and when your result would be 0.something, it's truncating to 0.

Make something a real value, and you're fine.  Or, multiply before dividing:

<del>int seconds = (int) ((float)elapsed.TotalSeconds / ItemPos) * (Count - ItemPos);</del>

(See below)

or

```
 int seconds = (int) (elapsed.TotalSeconds * (Count - ItemPos) / ItemPos);
```

**EDIT**

Based on dtb's comments, I realize I put my typecast in the wrongplace.  My first line won't work (though my second still will).  What's happening is you're taking the double value from TotalSeconds and dividing it by `int ItemPos` to get a double.  But then you're casting it to an int, which is where you get it set to 0.  As Henk Holterman said, you have to add extra parenthesis, so that the typecasting is over the entire division:

```
 int seconds = (int) ((elapsed.TotalSeconds / ItemPos) * (Count - ItemPos));
```

Comment: There is no integer division in the OP's code (assuming that `elapsed` is a TimeSpan). The problem is the position of the `(int)` cast.

Comment: If you have a non-negative `x` and a positive `y` where `x < y` then `(int)(x / y)` will always return 0, regardless if `x` is a double, float or int. The problem in the OP's code is not the division.

Answer (score 8):

Your expression is interpreted as

```
( (int)(elapsed.TotalSeconds / ItemPos) ) * (Count - ItemPos);
```

You have to delay the type-cast, all you need is an extra pair of `()`:

```
 //int seconds = (int)   (elapsed.TotalSeconds / ItemPos) * (Count - ItemPos)  ;
   int seconds = (int) ( (elapsed.TotalSeconds / ItemPos) * (Count - ItemPos) );
```